# SOCKET.IO LISTEN HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

i had my app with http, but i want add https, but i don't know how enable https on socket.io. The problem when i replaced http in 'require('socket.io)(https ....)' socket.io launch 404 error.

```
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http, { pingInterval: 2000, pingTimeout: 7000,});
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

io.on('connect', socket => {
    socket.on('ask', function(msg) {
        search
            .query(msg, socket.user, socket.token)
            .then(result => {
                socket.emit('response', result);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                socket.emit('response', {
                    msg: { text: "Lo siento, no puedo entender eso " },
                    type: 'error',
                });
            });
    });
    skills.registerClient(socket, socket.user).catch(err => {
        console.warn('Failed to register client', err);
    });
});

const port = await global.db.getGlobalValue('port');
    http.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server started on http://localhost:${port}`);
    });
    const sslPort = '1443';
    const server = https.createServer(httpsOptions, app)
    .listen(sslPort, () => {
        console.log(`Https server on https://localhost:${sslPort}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Currently using this:

```
const fs = require('fs'); 
const options = {
    rejectUnauthorized: true,
    key: fs.readFileSync('<SSL KEY PATH>/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('<SSL CERT PATH>/fullchain.pem')};
const app = require('https').createServer(options);
const io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', socket => {
      console.log("New Connection");
      socket.on('ask', function(msg) {
          //your code here
      });
});
app.listen(<PORT>); //e. g. 8080, Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to [create cert and key for ssl](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/).

After key and cert are generated, you can code like the following:

```
const express = require('express')
const https = require('https')
const fs = require('fs')
const port = 8888
const cert = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your_cert.cert')
const key = fs.readFileSync('/path/to/your_key.key')

const SSLOption = {
   key, cert
}
app = express()
let server = https.createServer(SSLOption, app)

server.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('server started on port: ' + port)
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.send('Working good...')
})

const io = require('socket.io')(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log(socket)
})
```

Comment: Did you create cert and key? And also notice that the port is 8888 in my code. You can change it to your taste. And in your code, there is no httpsOptions. It should be like SSLOption in my code :)

Comment: Look the images. I added certificate options.

Comment: The error was thrown at line 4. I wonder what code is there...

Comment: Can you contact me on facebook or another form?

Comment: You can open a chat room for this question.

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygulz.png)

[image]

[image]

This is the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
var httpsOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/ssl/localhost-key.pem')),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/ssl/localhost.pem'))
  };
```

This is my httpsOptions.